# Why does recursion not work?

Tags: c#

I need to delete a substring in a string. I need to remove a string starting from a particular character until another character. This is my code:

```
    [Test]
    public static void TestDeleteSign()
    {
        var s = "РасчНал[]{@ТипНП}/РасчНалГруп[]{@СубРФ}/@ДоляНалБаз";
        var result = DeleteSignature(s);
        var acceptResult = "РасчНал/РасчНалГруп/@ДоляНалБаз";
        Assert.AreEqual(acceptResult, result);
    }
    public static string DeleteSignature(string s)
    {
        if (s.Contains("[]{"))
        {
            var firstEntry = s.IndexOf("[]{");
            var closeEntry = s.IndexOf('}');
            s = s.Remove(firstEntry, closeEntry - firstEntry + 1);
            DeleteSignature(s);
        }
        return s;
    }
```

The result is:

```
Expected: "РасчНал/РасчНалГруп/@ДоляНалБаз"
But was: "РасчНал/РасчНалГруп[]{@СубРФ}/@ДоляНалБаз"
```

Comment: And what happens when you run that code? what did you find when you researched the problem?

Comment: Expected: "РасчНал/РасчНалГруп/@ДоляНалБаз"
But was:  "РасчНал/РасчНалГруп[]{@СубРФ}/@ДоляНалБаз"

Comment: Hint: a statement of `DeleteSignature(s);` isn't going to do anything useful, because you're not using the return value...

Comment: I do not want return value, before delete all substrings

Comment: You are not making use of the return value when you do the recursive call `DeleteSignature(s);`

Comment: Try it with `s =  DeleteSignature(s);`

Comment: @HenkHolterman you beat me to it!

Comment: @HenkHolterman you spoilt the fun :(

Comment: @ДенисМакушевский you need the return value. Strings are immutable data types, so if you're not receiving the output from your "inner" recursive methods, it won't reflect the changes on the "outer" recursive method. Also if you reassign the parameter's reference but don't return it, it won't affect the object anywhere else.

Comment: @CarbineCoder - we're not supposed to have fun here (anymore). Anyway, it's a beginner question but very well asked. Anyone who puts  Actual and  Expected results in a question deserves some encouragement.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Except they hadn't originally, that was edited in by someone else after someone prompted them with a comment

Comment: @HenkHolterman I agree. When Jon skeet gives a hint rather than answering it directly it implies - help the OP by trying to see where the problem lies rather than hand holding would be better solution on a longer run.

Comment: @Draken - right, i hadn't seen that.

Comment: You don't really need recursion here. Change `if` to `while` and remove the recursive call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function returns a string. After the first iteration of your function, your function is called a second time. Regardless of what happens there, your code will only return one passage removed as you do nothing with your recursive execution of `DeleteSignature(s)`. You need to return the output of your recursive execution like:

```
public static string DeleteSignature(string s)
{
    if (s.Contains("[]{"))
    {
        var firstEntry = s.IndexOf("[]{");
        var closeEntry = s.IndexOf('}');
        s = s.Remove(firstEntry, closeEntry - firstEntry + 1);
        return DeleteSignature(s);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I think the mistake OP made was thinking that reassigning s's reference would affect the object elsewhere, but that reference variable to s in each instance of DeleteSignature is independent of the other references to the same object.